# Import and save thumbnailphoto from ldap to django imagefield

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to save the picture of a user retrieved from active directory using django ldap library, but i am unable to store it in the right way, i have spent hours searching this issue, if any one can help me i will be grateful,
this the format of the thumbnail photo

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07\x06\x05\x08\x07\x07\x07\t\t\x08\n\x0c\x14\r\x0c\x0b\x0b\x0c\x19\x12\x13\x0f\x14\x1d\x1a\x1f\x1e\x1d\x1a\x1c\x1c $.\' ",#\x1c\x1c(7),01444\x1f\'9=82<.342\xff\xdb\x00C\x01\t\t\t\x0c\x0b\x0c\x18\r\r\x182!\x1c!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222\xff\xc0\x00\x11\x08\x00`\x00`\x03\x01!\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xff\xc4\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x01\x04\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x03\x06\x07\x00\x04\x05\x08\xff\xc4\x00:\x10\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02\x03\x05\x06\x04\x03\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x03\x04\x05\x11\x06!\x121a\x07\x14AQq\x13"2\x81\xa1\xc1#BR\x91\x15$r5C\x82\xa2\xb1\xb2\xc2\xd1\xe1\xff\xc4\x00\x19\x01\x00\x02\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x05\x04\xff\xc4\x00\x1d\x11\x01\x01\x01\x00\x03\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x11!\x12"1\xff\xda\x00\x0c\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xb3\x02 \x10\x04\x02\\&E\xc2\xcc 3\t0\x80B\x85\x00$ !\x00\xe0\x08\xc0H\xca\x02,&LP\xbb\xd6\xbem1\x11Y-\xf2\\\xe4$\x83)\xcb"\x1e\x87\x9b\xbdF\xddTu\xb9\x99\xedO\x18\xbb\xbeCt\x1a\xf2\xae9\xf8/\xd6gQ\xc3\x8c\x9a\x9aw\x99X\xde\xaen2\x07Q\x9c)\xa43ES\x04s\xc1#%\x86F\x871\xec9\x0e\x07\x91\x05,o;\x9e\xc1\xbe=b\xf9DP\xa9\xa0\x12\x84\x84\x19\xc0\x11\x00\x90\x10\x08\xb0\x99!z\xf6\xe9$r[\xec\xac\xda*\xde9*\x1c\x0e\t\x8d\x98\xf7=\x1cy\xf4\x18\xf1Z\xf6\xc0\xc7G\x82\xdc\x11\xcb\x03\x92\xcf\xed_w#C\xa9\x9f1i\xcb\x88\x02"Z\xd3\x9f4\xc6\x85\xac}%\xe2\xba\xccO\xf2\xcfgz\xa6g\x83\x0eq#GL\x90q\xea\x8e\xad\xf3~\x1fk>\xe3\xd4\xf0\xa1!h3\x82P\x90\x80p\x04a  \x12\xa6\x15\xce\xb9"MM\x03\xa2s^\xf8h\xdc\xc2?C\x8b\xb3\xbf\xa8!E(\xefwjz\xa6\x96T\xcb;G\xc6\xce\xee\x18\xdf\x91\xe6\xb8y|\xbb\xad\x0e\x19\xa9\x88\xdd\xd4\xb5u\xf3U63%S kZ\xe3\xdd\xcf\tv|\x13\xbab\xa9\xb6\xfb\xc5\xbe\xb2\xa9\xf3\xfb6:H\xcb\xa4\x19v\x1e\xdc\x0c\xf9\x8c\xe1G\x8f^yj\\\x98\xba\xf6E\xb8\xed\x8a\x12\xb4\x19\xa1(J\x01\xc0\x8c$\n\x11&\x15\xe6\xb6\x87\xb8\xdec\xadtn\xf6U\x1c,/\x03`q\x8d\xff\x00a\xfb\xae}EM\x0cT.\x99\xac\x19\xc7\xbcZ\x06@\xf1Y\xdc\xd9\xb3u\xab\xc1\xb9s\x03O|\xb6\\\xebOv\xcc\x91\xb66\x87\xf1\x01\x80G$\x0c?\xc4\xf5\x1d%\r$>\xd7$\xbd\xe0~V\x0ed\xf4\xdc(\xe7\x17\xf5\xf9K|\x92g\xf5\xea\xd4w2\x9b+M\x92D\x88\x07B \x91\t*a\x1f\xd6\x94o\xaf\xd2W8"\x19\x90Bd`\xf3,!\xdfe@\xc5^+e\x8e9\x9f#\xe3\x03\xe0\xe2\xd8\x95W$\xf7\xea\xde=y\xf2\xb7k\xe9{\xac\x1e\xdd\xd1\x1ag\xe31\xba9\x83\xb8\xbdp\x06\x02\x96\xf6E\xc5[~\xb9W8\x93\xeci\xc4c>ov\x7f\xe2\xa3\xc7\xf7\xea\xcek?\xc8\xb8\nl\xab
```

I have stored first the image bytes string in a field and then save it into the imagefield, but when i open it i have a message as if the format is not recognized by the photo editor.
This is the code that i have tried :

```
current_user = CustomUser.objects.filter(username=user).first()
                current_user.user_image.save('{0}/photos/{1}.jpg'.format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, username), ContentFile(current_user.user_image_string))
```

What is the next step that i have to do ?

UPDATE :

```
                try:
                    result = CustomUser.user_image_string
                    thumbnail = result[0][1]['thumbnailPhoto'][0]
                    save_avatar(CustomUser, thumbnail)
                    print('* %s: %d' % (CustomUser.username, len(thumbnail)))
                except Exception as e:
                    print('  %s: error: %s' % (CustomUser.username, str(e)))
                def save_avatar(CustomUser, thumbnail):
                    buffer = io.BytesIO()
                    buffer.write(thumbnail)
                    image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(buffer, None, 'test.png', 'image/png', buffer.getbuffer().nbytes, None)
                    CustomUser.user_image.save('user_image', image_file)
```

Comment: Did you try passing the bytes directly to `ContentFile`?

Comment: Hi Tarun, actually current_user.user_image_string is a bytes that i have copied in the top of the question

Comment: Can you do a hex comparison of the saved file and see if it is the same or something changes?

Comment: It gives some other bunch of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working snippets from a production code used to retrieve thumbnailPhoto from LDAP server and save it into UserProfile, with Python 3.7 and Django 2.x
Hope this helps ...

```
import io
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile

...
try:
    thumbnail = result[0][1]['thumbnailPhoto'][0]
    save_avatar(user, thumbnail)
    print('* %s: %d' % (user.username, len(thumbnail)))
except Exception as e:
    print('  %s: error: %s' % (user.username, str(e)))

...

def save_avatar(user, thumbnail):
    try:
        profile = user.profile
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        profile=UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write(thumbnail)
    image_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(buffer, None, 'test.png', 'image/png', buffer.getbuffer().nbytes, None)
    profile.avatar.save('avatar', image_file)
```

where:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=True)
```

### BRIEF EXPLANATION

1) The binary stream received by the LDAP server, which contains the bitmap, is copied into a memory buffer (io.BytesIO in Python3)

2) A "fake" InMemoryUploadedFile() object is initialised from that buffer

3) The object created in (2) can be conveniently saved into the ImageField of the Model

Comment: i have updated the question with your answer you can check it, but i have a new error now  <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x7f0862943be0>: error: 'DeferredAttribute' object does not support indexing

Comment: Can you supply the full stack trace ? Could be a problem more related to the Django Model that to LDAP itself. You might also try the code with a simplified Model (a very very simple one with no relations and just an ImageField) as a POC

Comment: sorry for my late answer, i had another stuff to do, actually the problem is that i have even tried to convert the bytes stream received from ldap with some online tool and they are unable to convert it to the right picture, i have always a small blank square

Comment: actually after playing around with your code i am able to retrieve and store and display the picture, i wanna thank you so much, you don't have any idea how much i was struggling with this

Comment: I'm glad it helped ;)